# Positioning within a HTML form

Tags: html, css

I realize this is a very basic issue.

I am currently trying to create a website http://theviewbeyond.co.uk/.

I am currently adding a contact form to which I have created a picture to use as the background of the form, the issue is I cannot move the objects within the form such as text boxes to within the picture.

I have tried absolute positioning which doesn't seem to work either.

How can I do this ?

```
form {
margin: 0 auto;
width: 60%;
background-image: url("../IMG/contactpage1[2742].jpg"); 
background-size: cover;
```

Comment: Can you please show your code?

Comment: Please edit your question and add your code, not putting it in comment.

Comment: Please include the html for the form we get a better idea of context

Answer (score 0):

set the picture to your background:

```
<div id="container" style='background-image:url("IMG/slidermockup[2710].jpg");'></div>
```

Comment: My issue still persists as cant i need to position the form, its the contact page im looking at, sorry uif that wasnt clear

Comment: supply a snippet and explain more clearly what you want to do

Answer (score 0):

I was reviewing your site and see your problem, I was trying some styles and I realice that `background-image` doesn't fit correctly if your container has a different size of your image so you need to play with the `height` and `width` of your form.

```
margin: 0 auto;
background-image: url(../IMG/contactpage1[2742].jpg);
background-position: center center;
background-size: cover;
height: 350px;
width: 370px;
```

In different screen sizes you'll need to use [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/CSS/Media_queries) to make it work well.

Answer (score 0):

I've used a `fieldset` as a supplimental container and positioned your from elements in this using `padding`. Change the padding values asrequired

```css
fieldset {
  border: 0;
  padding-top: 400px;
  padding-left: 175px;
}

form {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 60%;
  background-image: url("http://theviewbeyond.co.uk/IMG/contactpage1[2742].jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  height: 900px;
}
```

```html
<div id="Contact">
  <form>
    <fieldset>
      <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="NAME">
      <input type="text" id="email" placeholder="EMAIL">
      <input type="number" id="number" placeholder="PHONE">
      <input type="text" id="Event" placeholder="Type Of Event">
      <textarea name="message" placeholder="MESSAGE"></textarea>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>
```

[Arnolds answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44448877/4665) also has valid point regarding image size and media queries

Comment: @Jackb2296 upvotes and accepting the answer is always appreciated.